# ¿ayuda con ventana modal en css para que aparezca adelante de toda la ventana y no atrás?

Tags: modal, ventana

Necesito ayuda pues copie un codigo de ventana modal para html y css, y el problema que tengo esque la ventana me aparece atras de todo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven cuando hago clic en política de privacidad se abre la ventana modal pero sale atrás de todo ¿cómo logro de que aparezca adelante? Aquí les pongo mi codigo css para que me lo corrijan y también les pongo el html

```css
a.open{
 background-color: #414141;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 margin: 20px;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 position: absolute;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #000;
 

}


section.modalDialog{
 background-color: white;
 bottom: 0;
 top:0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: -2;
}

section.modalDialog:target{
 opacity: 1;
}

a.close{
 background-color: #414141;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 22px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 5px;
 top:5px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 28px;
}

a.close{
 background-color: #000;
}

section.modal{
 background-color: #111;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 10% auto;
 padding: 20px;
 position: relative;
 width: 400px;
}

h2{
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 2em;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

p{
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<header>
 

<div class="logotipo"><img src="imagenes/alex.bmp" width="70" alt="logotipo"> </div>
 <nav>
 <ul><li><a href="#">INICIO</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ACERCA DE</a></li>
  <li><div class="contenedor">
   <a href="#openmodal" class="open"> politica de privacidad</a>
   <section id="openmodal" class="modalDialog">
    <section class="modal">
     <a href="#close" class="close"> X </a>
     <h2> politica de privacidad</h2>
     <p>Esta permitido compartir todo el contenido de este sitio, más no está permitido ...</p>
    </section>
   </section>
  </div></li>
  <li><a href="#">CONTACTO</a></li>
  <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsYcSASeuWbHFBZJXy6SJEA?sub_confirmation=1">YOUTUBE</a></li>
 </ul>
   </nav>
  </header>
```

Comment: El z-index debe darle un valor más alto, ese es el que sobrepone a los de más elementos del DOM, puede darle el valor 1000  `section.modalDialog{z-index: -2;}` a `section.modalDialog{z-index: 1000;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que al tener un `z-index` negativo se muestra detrás de los demás elementos.

La propiedad `z-index` marca qué elementos se muestran delante y cuales detrás. Se muestran encima los que tienen un valor mayor y por detrás los que tienen menor valor. Por defecto todos tienen valor `0` así que al darle un valor negativo estás indicando que se muestre por delante.

El problema es que si lo pones delante no vas a poder interactuar con la pantalla, porque realmente no ocultas el diálogo, lo que estás haciendo es darle un `opacity: 0`, es decir, hacerlo transparente.

Sería mejor que lo ocultaras con un `display: none` y a lo mostraras con `display: block` en lugar de jugar con la propiedad `opacity`:

```css
a.open{
 background-color: #414141;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 margin: 20px;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 position: absolute;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #000;
 

}


section.modalDialog{
 background-color: white;
 bottom: 0;
 top:0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 position: fixed;
  display: none;
 z-index: 2;
}

section.modalDialog:target{
 display: block;
}

a.close{
 background-color: #414141;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 22px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 5px;
 top:5px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 28px;
}

a.close{
 background-color: #000;
}

section.modal{
 background-color: #111;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 10% auto;
 padding: 20px;
 position: relative;
 width: 400px;
}

h2{
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 2em;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

p{
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="logotipo"><img src="imagenes/alex.bmp" width="70" alt="logotipo"> </div>
 <nav>
 <ul><li><a href="#">INICIO</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ACERCA DE</a></li>
  <li><div class="contenedor">
   <a href="#openmodal" class="open"> politica de privacidad</a>
   <section id="openmodal" class="modalDialog">
    <section class="modal">
     <a href="#close" class="close"> X </a>
     <h2> politica de privacidad</h2>
     <p>Esta permitido compartir todo el contenido de este sitio, más no está permitido ...</p>
    </section>
   </section>
  </div></li>
  <li><a href="#">CONTACTO</a></li>
  <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsYcSASeuWbHFBZJXy6SJEA?sub_confirmation=1">YOUTUBE</a></li>
 </ul>
   </nav>
  </header>
```

Comment: hola ayudame con esto; en móviles cuando se desplaza la barra mas grande de arriba a abajo e una pequeña porción de la página en la parte inferior se ve el contenido de lo que esta atrás, cosa que no quiero https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/244691/hola-en-mi-p%C3%A1gina-cuando-haces-clic-en-pol%C3%ADtica-de-privacidad-en-los-m%C3%B3viles-en